# Neo4j merge's not saving data

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graphaware

I have the following code using PHP & GraphAware:

```
$stack = $client->stack();
$stack->push('  MATCH (student:Student{id:123})
        MATCH (spring:Term{name:"Spring2017"})
        MATCH (class:Class{name:"Cypher101"})
        MERGE (student)-[:ENROLLED_IN]->(class)-[:FOR_TERM]->(spring)');
$results = $client->runStack($stack);

$res = $client->run('MATCH (n) RETURN count(n)');
print_r($res->records());
```

I have copied the example code found here: https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/understanding-how-merge-works/ and for some reason the print_r() returns the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => GraphAware\Bolt\Record\RecordView Object
        (
            [keys:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => count(n)
                )

            [values:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                )

            [keyToIndexMap:GraphAware\Bolt\Record\RecordView:private] => Array
                (
                    [count(n)] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

If I run a CREATE command the query works fine but for some reason the code above won't. Can someone advise me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your query seems correct. Can you check if the nodes you are matching exists in the database?

Comment: Try this from Neo4j browser, if it works you may have missed something in your PHP code.

Comment: They don't exist - because I though the merge would create them if not?

Comment: Then you should replace `MATCH` with `MERGE` in the first 3 lines.

Comment: Oh perfect!! Please make that an answer and I'll award it :o)

Comment: Just one thing though - will that not overwrrite existing ones if there is a later duplicate?

Comment: Nope, Merge will not overwrite. I recommend to create these nodes separately and keep your query as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your query seems correct.**

**Check if these nodes exist in the Neo4j Database.**

- If these are not present in the database first create these nodes and
  then run the query.
- You can also replace `MATCH` with `MERGE`, in that case, you don't
  have to create these nodes separately.

> NOTE: Multiple `MERGE` in a single query is not recommended, so try to
>   use the first solution (creating the nodes separately).